# Is it possible to access Virtual Machine memory from the host without being visible to any process in the Virtual Machine?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware, shared-memory

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to access all the OS memory from a Virtual Machine from the host without being visible to the Virtual Machine's processes. And if so how would somebody go about doing this?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but the VM is just a process on the host. So, you could just dump the guest process' memory into a file, and examine the file.

Comment: OK, and how would I go about making this file and accessing it from the host?

Comment: It depends on the host OS, which you haven't mentioned. Search for "<your OS> dump process memory". Also, some hypervisors may offer dumping the guest VM's memory.

Comment: The os in question is Windows for both the host and guest

Comment: You need to understand how the virtual machine implementation api works in order to understand what you need to do to snoop on it.   You can try to extract that bit by bit from SO questions, but I would expect to see you still here in 2 years asking `how do I know where to find the memory for *(%edi)`.  If you want to hack, you need to grab an axe and start chopping -- there is no magic `make a tree fall` twig.